# angular js datetimepicker не выпадает календарь

Tags: angularjs, дата, datetime, datepicker

Установил на форме календарь при помощи директивы datetimepicker, а он не всегда отрабатывает. В чем может быть причина? В каком направлении копать?

```
<div class="dropdown form-group col-md-3">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownStart" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#"
       href="#">
        <div class="input-group date">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" data-ng-model="item.recall_date">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
        </div>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
        <datetimepicker data-ng-model="item.recall_date"
                        data-datetimepicker-config="{ dropdownSelector: '#dropdownStart'}"
                        data-on-set-time="onTimeSet(newDate, oldDate)">

        </datetimepicker>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Есть ли какие-нибудь ошибки в консоле?